# JQuery - Table Calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table generated from database. And each field hidden until selected from select dropdown list. Also need calculate visible rows. I have this code, but it calculates all rows, even visibly. Could you advice how I can fix the code to calculate only visibly rows.

TABLE:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" id="sum_table">
    <tr style="color:white;background:gray;">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="one">
        <td>Service 1</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>54</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="two">
        <td>Service 2</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="three">
        <td>Service 3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="result" style="background:silver;">
        <td>TOTAL:</td>
        <td id="total1">0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>ADD LINE:
<select id="select_stud">
    <option>-- Select --</option>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#one').hide();
  $('#two').hide();
  $('#three').hide();

  $('#select_stud').change(function () {
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
  })
});


$("#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").text(function(i){
    var t = 0;
    $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i+2)+")").each(function(){
        t += parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
    });
    return "= " + t;
});
```

Also I need to calculate only 2 columns.

**Here is full code:** http://jsfiddle.net/stanencendo/u7a27vth/9/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/u7a27vth/10/

To only look at visible rows when calculating your sum, you can add a condition like this:

```
if ( $(this).parent().css('display') != 'none' )
```

You'll also want to update the sums every time you add a new column.  You can do that by wrapping your sum calculation in a function (in this case, updateSums) and call it within your change function for the select element:

```
$('#select_stud').change(function () {
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    updateSums();
})
```

That said, your approach probably isn't the best way to handle this.  Typically, you want your view to be derived from your data, not the other way around.

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, if you want the last column to be calculated as well, you need to change `$("#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first,:last)")` to `$("#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first)")`

It wasn't clear to me whether or not this was you intention.

Comment: great work! also dont forget to modify you selector from: $("#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first,**:last**)") to $("#sum_table tr:last td:not(**:first**)") to include the last column :)

Comment: I need to calculate only two columns, COLUMN 1 & COLUMN 2 excludin any other columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").text(function(i){
    var t = 0;
    $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i+2)+")").filter(":visible").each(function(){
        t += parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
    });
    return "= " + t;
});
```